# Carriage Return showing in notepad++ but not textpad?

Tags: newline, notepad++, textpad

I have some text files copied out to a server.  I typically use and prefer notepad++ to look at text files but on this server, only textpad is installed.  This is really strange behavior but I noticed that when I view the EOL chars in notepad++ I can clearly see and search for the CRLF (i.e. \r\n).  But when I display the same files in textpad, I am able to search only on the LF (\n) and do not have any hits on the CR (\r).  Am I missing something on how Textpad is interpreting the EOL chars?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kyslik.  I don't typically use TextPad but that is what is installed out on the server.  When I view the files in notepad++ on my desktop I can see the CRLF (\r\n) and I can search for them.  When I view the same files using Textpad and search for CRLF(\r\n) I only get hits on LF(\n) and not CR(\r).  Do I have something wrong with my settings or does Textpad just truly interpret CRLF as (\n) instead of (\r\n)?

Comment: `newline` differs in all 3 most common operation systems (Windows, Linux and Mac OS) I bet you knew this.  `notepad++` as far as I know is much robust and therefore `newlines` are "autodetected" and I bet you can even set how is program "showing" (rendering) them in text area. As it seems yes TextPad interpret CRLF as `\n` even on windows machine. But take a look in [release notes](http://www.textpad.com/support/relnotes.html) of TextPad => `In regular expressions in macros, [^...] is now changed to [^...\r\n] to constrain it to the end of line`. I don't know If I helped.

Answer (score 22):

This happens when the EOL control characters are not correct. Windows represents newlines with the carriage return + line feed.

In Notepad++, you can check for these characters by selecting:

View > Show Symbols > [x] Show End of Line

[image: notepad++]

You need to modify your script so your data is formatted like this:

CRLF

Answer (score 2):

Yes ideally it's carriage return and followed by line feed,

\r\n

but you can also use a quick shorthand to place {lf} rather then {cr}{lf}

\n

Answer (score 1):

*I know this is a slightly old question, but I struggled with this exact problem, and here is how I found a workaround.*

When using `Save As` in textpad you can specify the file format at the bottom (`PC`, `UNIX`, or `Mac`). If you choose `UNIX` in theory this ends lines only with the `\n` character, however you have to change this option every time.

You can change the preferences for specific "Document Classes" to specify the output file format. Follow these steps:

- Click `Configure`
- Go to `Preferences`
- Expand the `Document Classes` list
- Select `bash`, which should include `*.sh` files
- Scroll down the options on the right until you see `Create new files as`
- Select `UNIX`

This *should* now save all `*.sh` files you create as UNIX format without the carriage returns. Good luck

I found this info here:
http://homes.ori.org/~keiths/Files/Tips/Software_TextPad_Prefs.html#DocClasses