# No new line after tags in generated weka ARFF File

Tags: java, dataset, weka, arff

I am using weka in my Java code. One part of my system builds an ARFF File which can later be used to build a Classifier. Long story short:

I used these two weka tutorials on how to build my ARFF File from code:

[Build dataset](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Programmatic+Use)

[Save dataset to ARFF](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Save+Instances+to+an+ARFF+File)

My code is very close to what they did in these tutorials. Note for the second tutorial: I used the ARFFSaver. (I already used Java I/O but it doesn't change anything)

My result file looks like this:

```
@relation Rel@attribute string-a {ab,cd}@attribute string-b{ab,cd}@attributetime-a numeric@attribute time-b numeric@attribute Class {a,b,c}@dataab,cd,1,2,a
```

But obviously it should look like this:

```
@relation Rel
@attribute string-a {ab,cd}
@attribute string-b{ab,cd}
@attributetime-a numeric
@attribute time-b numeric
@attribute Class {a,b,c}
@data
ab,cd,1,2,a
```

Of course i can build the file completely manually line by line, but i would prefer to use the weka code.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the problem seems to be a Windows Editor issue. I just opened the ARFF File with Notepad++ where the file is shown correctly. So the linebreaks are already there but not shown by the Editor. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088242/carriage-return-showing-in-notepad-but-not-textpad).